# Safest way to open a file in python 3.4

Tags: python, file

I was expecting the following would work but PyDev is returning an error:

```
try fh = open(myFile):
    logging.info("success")
except Exception as e:
    logging.critical("failed because:")
    logging.critical(e)
```

gives

```
Encountered "fh" at line 237, column 5. Was expecting:     ":"...
```

I've looked around and cannot find a safe way to open a filehandle for reading in Python 3.4 and report errors properly.  Can someone point me in the correct direction please?

Comment: Fun fact: The error you got is exactly what was wrong. I'll admit that's not always the case, but don't forget to read the error message.

Answer (score 4):

You misplaced the `:`; it comes directly after `try`; it is better to put that on its own, separate line:

```
try:
    fh = open(myFile)
    logging.info("success")
except Exception as e:
    logging.critical("failed because:")
    logging.critical(e)
```

You placed the `:` after the `open()` call instead.

Instead of passing in `e` as a separate argument, you can tell `logging` to pick up the exception automatically:

```
try:
    fh = open(myFile)
    logging.info("success")
except Exception:
    logging.critical("failed because:", exc_info=True)
```

and a full traceback will be included in the log. This is what the [`logging.exception()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.exception) does; it'll call `logging.error()` with `exc_info` set to true, producing a message at log level `ERROR` plus a traceback.